# How to programmatically create WPF Grid.RowDefintion.Height binding

Tags: wpf, multibinding, programmatically-created, rowdefinition

This should be simple, but I'm stuck! How to create the following multibinding **in code** and apply it to the given row definition:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition.Height>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="obj1" Path="x"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="obj2" Path="y"/> 
                </MultiBinding>
            </RowDefinition.Height>   
        </RowDefinition>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
//Create binding
var binding = new MultiBinding
{
    Converter = new MyMultiConverter()
};
binding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("x") { ElementName = "obj1" });
binding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("y") { ElementName = "obj2" });

//create RowDefinition
var definition = new RowDefinition();
//set binding on HeightProperty
definition.SetBinding(RowDefinition.HeightProperty, binding);

//'myGrid' is the name of the grid instance
//add RowDefinition to grid
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(definition);
```

To be able to handle the grid in codebehind you add a name to the grid:

```
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks! The definition.SetBinding was the missing piece of the puzzle for me.

Comment: If you ever stumple into a class which don't have the `SetBinding`, but still inherits from `DependencyObject`, then you can set bindings via `BindingOperations.SetBinding` instead.